# How do I create an operation to check if there is a schedule overwriting an existing one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datetime

I need to do a validation when I try to add a new schedule to my system.
The class has a StartAppointment and EndAppointment property:

```
public class Appointment : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime StartAppointment { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndAppointment { get; set; }
    public int Weekday { get; set; }
    public int Vacancies { get; set; }

    public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
}
```

So, when I add the new entity goes through verification to ensure that the schedule doesn't overlap an existing one:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Notification>> ValidateAdd(AppointmentViewModel model)
    {
        var appointments = await _appointmentRepo.FindBy(x => x.ActivityId == model.ActivityId).ToListAsync();
        var isReapeted = (appointments.Any(x => 
            (x.StartAppointment <= model.StartAppointment && x.EndAppointment <= model.EndAppointment
            || x.EndAppointment <= model.StartAppointment && x.EndAppointment <= model.EndAppointment)
            && x.Weekday == model.Weekday)
        ) ? true : false;
```

Unfortunately, my code doesn't validate correctly and returns an overlapping message even when there are no overlapping schedules.
If you know how to solve this problem, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: `x.StartAppointment <= model.StartAppointment` should be `x.StartAppointment >= model.StartAppointment`  (greater than)

Comment: Also, you need to check both start and end times of your candidate appointment against the range (start and end times) of every other appointment.  Scheduling is hard.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so, just using an Any() on appointments doesn't do it?

Comment: It will if you get your conditions right.

Comment: Draw it out on a piece of paper, and then rewrite your conditions.  Make sure you check both your candidate start time and candidate end time.